# IndexedDB events do not fire

Tags: events, indexeddb

I am using Firefox 21. I wrote the code below to display the contents of an indexedDB object store on page load.

```
      window.indexedDB = window.indexedDB || window.mozIndexedDB || window.webkitIndexedDB ||
                         window.msIndexedDB;    
      window.IDBTransaction = window.IDBTransaction || window.webkitIDBTransaction ||
                         window.msIDBTransaction;
      window.IDBKeyRange = window.IDBKeyRange || window.webkitIDBKeyRange ||
                         window.msIDBKeyRange;

      var request = window.indexedDB.open('mgDB', 1);
      request.onerror = function(e) {
           alert('error');
      };

      request.onupgradeneeded = function(e) {
           alert('upgradeneeded');
      };

      request.onsuccess = function(e) {
           alert('success'); 
      };
```

Knowing that mgDB does not exist yet, I expected the upgradeneeded event to fire. When I debugged the code using Firebug, I see error, onsuccess and onupgradeneeded having null values, so none of the events fired. When I execute the code without debug mode, I see the success event being fired. Does anyone know why that happens?

Answer (score 4):

The fact that the onupgradeneeded doesn't fire is because you ran the code already several time and the database with version one is made the first time. The logic of the open function is, create the db if it doesn't exist, upgrade if the version of the database is lower than the provided version. (Keep in mind the indexeddb is persistent storage, meaning it isn't destroyed if you close the browser)  If you want to be sure you want to enter the onupgradeneeded every time (for testing pupouses!!!) you can delete the database before opening/creating it again.

The fact that the events are null is maybe the depending on the place you put your breakpoint? Put a breakpoint in one of the callbacks, and you will see the onsuccess, onerror, ... will be filled up on the request object.

Comment: You are right about the need to delete the database and start afresh when I need to test. Let me elaborate a bit more on how I have been testing. Yesterday, when I started testing, I saw the onerror event fire a couple of times. Then, before each time I tested, I deleted the databse manually, and saw the onsuccess event fire consistently. This morning, I tested again by deleting the database manually AND clearing the Firefox cache+cookies, and I saw the onupgradeneeded AND success events both fire consistently.

Comment: That is how it should be, if you upgrade, the onupgradeneeded is fired first. In this you can edit the structure. Once this is done, the connection to the database is opened and you can start using it for reading, inserting, deleting, ... data.